# How can I do the custom pagination 

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm trying to configure a jQuery pagination for my website. I've configured a pagination which is based on counting the `<p>` tags. But requirement is to be custom paginated. Like using some `<!--pagebreak-->` tags or something like that. How can I do the custom pagination using jQuery and custom `<!--pagebreak-->` tag. Please suggest any pagination script using jQuery and custom `<!--pagebreak-->` tag

```
<div class="storybody">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis lacinia ante sit amet porta. Vivamus ut interdum massa. Etiam feugiat commodo accumsan. Suspendisse vulputate faucibus erat, non eleifend arcu iaculis et. Nulla at eros eu velit gravida ullamcorper nec id erat. In in velit mauris, vitae pretium purus. Ut scelerisque pellentesque fermentum. Curabitur nec mauris eu diam pulvinar cursus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. Vivamus id elementum sem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis lacinia ante sit amet porta. Vivamus ut interdum massa. Etiam feugiat commodo accumsan. Suspendisse vulputate faucibus erat, non eleifend arcu iaculis et. Nulla at eros eu velit gravida ullamcorper nec id erat. In in velit mauris, vitae pretium purus. Ut scelerisque pellentesque fermentum. Curabitur nec mauris eu diam pulvinar cursus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. Vivamus id elementum sem.</p>
    <!--pagebreak-->
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis lacinia ante sit amet porta. Vivamus ut interdum massa. Etiam feugiat commodo accumsan. Suspendisse vulputate faucibus erat, non eleifend arcu iaculis et. Nulla at eros eu velit gravida ullamcorper nec id erat. In in velit mauris, vitae pretium purus. Ut scelerisque pellentesque fermentum. Curabitur nec mauris eu diam pulvinar cursus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. Vivamus id elementum sem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis lacinia ante sit amet porta. Vivamus ut interdum massa. Etiam feugiat commodo accumsan. Suspendisse vulputate faucibus erat, non eleifend arcu iaculis et. Nulla at eros eu velit gravida ullamcorper nec id erat. In in velit mauris, vitae pretium purus. Ut scelerisque pellentesque fermentum. Curabitur nec mauris eu diam pulvinar cursus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. Vivamus id elementum sem.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis lacinia ante sit amet porta. Vivamus ut interdum massa. Etiam feugiat commodo accumsan. Suspendisse vulputate faucibus erat, non eleifend arcu iaculis et. Nulla at eros eu velit gravida ullamcorper nec id erat. In in velit mauris, vitae pretium purus. Ut scelerisque pellentesque fermentum. Curabitur nec mauris eu diam pulvinar cursus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. Vivamus id elementum sem.</p>
    <!--pagebreak-->
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis lacinia ante sit amet porta. Vivamus ut interdum massa. Etiam feugiat commodo accumsan. Suspendisse vulputate faucibus erat, non eleifend arcu iaculis et. Nulla at eros eu velit gravida ullamcorper nec id erat. In in velit mauris, vitae pretium purus. Ut scelerisque pellentesque fermentum. Curabitur nec mauris eu diam pulvinar cursus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. Vivamus id elementum sem.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool story, what's the question?

Comment: Can you tell us what is the question here? What do you want be specific...

Comment: You can just configure your pagination to use your HTML comments as page breaks

Comment: I think the fock needs some jquery pagination scripts..

You can try here.. http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

Comment: yes I want a jquery solution for custom the pagination. Using custom pagination tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some thing on my own.You can check the code in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAbhishekk/NeHxy/18/). I have used Jquery1.3.2. and  [jquery.pajinate.js](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4151695/html/pajinate/examples/js/jquery.pajinate.js).

HTML:

```
<div id="paging_container8" class="container">
                
                <div class="page_navigation"></div>
                <div class="storybody">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis lacinia ante sit amet porta. Vivamus ut interdum massa. Etiam feugiat commodo accumsan. Suspendisse vulputate faucibus erat, non eleifend arcu iaculis et. Nulla at eros eu velit gravida ullamcorper nec id erat. In in velit mauris, vitae pretium purus. Ut scelerisque pellentesque fermentum. Curabitur nec mauris eu diam pulvinar cursus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. Vivamus id elementum sem.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis lacinia ante sit amet porta. Vivamus ut interdum massa. Etiam feugiat commodo accumsan. Suspendisse vulputate faucibus erat, non eleifend arcu iaculis et. Nulla at eros eu velit gravida ullamcorper nec id erat. In in velit mauris, vitae pretium purus. Ut scelerisque pellentesque fermentum. Curabitur nec mauris eu diam pulvinar cursus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. Vivamus id elementum sem.</p>
                    <!--pagebreak-->
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis lacinia ante sit amet porta. Vivamus ut interdum massa. Etiam feugiat commodo accumsan. Suspendisse vulputate faucibus erat, non eleifend arcu iaculis et. Nulla at eros eu velit gravida ullamcorper nec id erat. In in velit mauris, vitae pretium purus. Ut scelerisque pellentesque fermentum. Curabitur nec mauris eu diam pulvinar cursus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. Vivamus id elementum sem.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis lacinia ante sit amet porta. Vivamus ut interdum massa. Etiam feugiat commodo accumsan. Suspendisse vulputate faucibus erat, non eleifend arcu iaculis et. Nulla at eros eu velit gravida ullamcorper nec id erat. In in velit mauris, vitae pretium purus. Ut scelerisque pellentesque fermentum. Curabitur nec mauris eu diam pulvinar cursus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. Vivamus id elementum sem.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis lacinia ante sit amet porta. Vivamus ut interdum massa. Etiam feugiat commodo accumsan. Suspendisse vulputate faucibus erat, non eleifend arcu iaculis et. Nulla at eros eu velit gravida ullamcorper nec id erat. In in velit mauris, vitae pretium purus. Ut scelerisque pellentesque fermentum. Curabitur nec mauris eu diam pulvinar cursus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. Vivamus id elementum sem.</p>
                    <!--pagebreak-->
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lobortis lacinia ante sit amet porta. Vivamus ut interdum massa. Etiam feugiat commodo accumsan. Suspendisse vulputate faucibus erat, non eleifend arcu iaculis et. Nulla at eros eu velit gravida ullamcorper nec id erat. In in velit mauris, vitae pretium purus. Ut scelerisque pellentesque fermentum. Curabitur nec mauris eu diam pulvinar cursus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse eu ipsum augue. Vivamus id elementum sem.</p>
                    </div>
                
                
            </div> ​
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
var str= $(".storybody").html();
var substr=str.split( "<!--pagebreak-->" );
var txt="<ul class='storycontent'><li>";
var x=0;
for (x in substr)
  {
    if(x==0){
        txt=txt+substr[x];
    }
    else{
          txt=txt+"</li><li>"+substr[x];
    }
  }
var paginated=txt+"</li></ul>";
$('div.storybody').replaceWith(paginated);

$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#paging_container8').pajinate({
                    num_page_links_to_display : 2,
                    items_per_page : 1 ,
                    item_container_id : '.storycontent'
                });
            });
​</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for example:

Comment tag are `nodeType == 8` so based of your input you can read in this way:

```
var el = []; //[2,3,1]

var sum = 0;

$(".storybody").contents().filter(function(){
    if($(this).is("p")) sum++; //how many p before a comment
    if(this.nodeType === 8){
        el.push(sum);
        sum = 0;
    }
});
```

and for example based of el array this could be a next and prev function, but it's **could be done in a better way**, but this is only an example ;-)

```
//Next and Prev function
var curr = 0;
var k = 0;

$("#next").on("click", function(){
    if(curr < el.length){
        $(".storybody p").hide();
        var e = range(k, el[curr], ".storybody p", "next");
        $(e).each(function(){$(this).show()});                
        k += el[curr];                    
        curr++;
    }else{
        console.log("last page!");         
    }                  
});

$("#prev").on("click", function(){
    if(curr > 0){
        $(".storybody p").hide();
        var e = range(k, el[curr-1], ".storybody p", "prev");
        $(e).each(function(){$(this).show()});
        k -= el[curr-1];                    
        curr--;
    }else{
        console.log("first page!");         
    }
});


function range(s,e,sel,ac){

    if(ac == "next"){
        var elms = [];
        for(var i = s; i < (e+s); i++){
            elms.push($(sel).eq(i));
        }
    }else if(ac == "prev"){
        var elms = [];
        for(var i = (s-e); i < s; i++){
            elms.push($(sel).eq(i));
        }
    }
    return elms;
}
```

PS: assume that i've added anoher `<!--pagebreak-->` to the end of p tag (before )